# Prevent link return false with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, navigation

I'm using navigation with a fullscreen overlay, triggered by a menu button in a fixed position at the top of the screen. This means the overlay can be opened when the browser has scrolled to the bottom of the page. By default the script will make the browser return to the top of the page when the menu button is clicked. So to prevent this happening I've added 'return: false' to a click function.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#trigger-overlay').click(function() {
    $('section.header header h1').toggleClass('change');
    $('section.header header h2').toggleClass('change');
    return false;
  });
});
```

But this now means the links in the navigation will not return the browser to the top of the following page. I'm guessing I need to target the links in the navigation menu to stop this happening, but I can't seem to get it to work.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.overlay li a').click(function() {
    return true;
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible approach is checking whether or not the actually clicked element is the 'white-listed' link (or its descendant); if not, just don't do `return false`. Here's how it can be done:

```
$('#trigger-overlay').click(function(evt) {
  $('section.header header h1').toggleClass('change'); 
  $('section.header header h2').toggleClass('change');

  var $target = $(evt.target);
  if ($target.closest('.overlay').length === 0) { // not inside overlay
    return false;
  }
});
```

Comment: This didn't quite work, so for now I've used this:      `   $(document).ready(function(){
        $("nav a").click(function(){
            $("html,body").scrollTop(0);
    });`